# Why can't product of regression coefficient be greater than1?

Tags: statistics, computational-mathematics

Given that Regression coefficients are just slopes of equations of lines representing x over y and y over x, why can't their product be more than one.

I get the fact that they are related to correlation coefficient which lies between -1 and 1, but looking just at the slope values, would not the product of slopes (say, m=57.28 for 89 degrees and m=1 for 45 degrees with X axis) be greater than 1?

I am really confused about the interpretation.

Comment: https://sebastiansauer.github.io/why-abs-correlation-is-max-1/

Comment: Are you asking why with data $\{(x_i,y_i)\}$ and least square models $\hat y_i=m_1x_i+c_1$ and $\hat x_i =m_2y_i+c_2$ you get $m_1 m_2 \le 1$?  This is precisely because $m_1=\rho \frac{s_y}{s_x}$ and $m_2=\rho \frac{s_x}{s_y}$ where the regression residuals (i.e. lack of correlation) pull both slopes towards $0$.  So you can say $m_1 m_2=\rho^2 \le 1$, with equality only if all the points lie on the regression lines